Uploading file with playwright from API
I am trying to upload a file with an API in the following test:
test('change avatar', async ({ request }) => {

    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../files/photo1.jpg');

    // Create a form data object with the file
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        console.log('File exists:', filePath);
    } else {
        console.error('File does not exist:', filePath);
    }
    // Create a FormData instance
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileBuffer, {
        filename: 'photo1.jpg',
        contentType: 'image/jpg'
    });
    const userRequestBody = {
        formData
    };
    
    const content = await functions.performRequest(request, 'post', baseUrl + 'users/'+data.currentUser+ '/avatars', userRequestBody);
    console.log(content)
})

I am trying to pass the formData into the body of the request but I am getting the following error:

{"message":"File is required","error":"Bad Request","statusCode":400}

The documentation says the request body needs multipart/form-data and file string ($binary).
Also when running the endpoint from postman, this is a fully functional curl:
curl --location 'https://api.example.com/users/66950baa95ea581795bc5d2b/avatars' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...
--form 'file=@"/D:/media/photo1.jpg"'

How can I rewrite my test so that I upload the file successfully?

What does functions.performRequest() do?
